# Why is function nextPrime just returning next number greater than n?

Tags: c, function

I was trying to make a code that inputs natural number n and outputs first prime number greater than n. I used 2 functions *isPrime* and *nextPrime.* Question is, why is output always just n+1?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int isPrime(int n)
{
    if(n<2)return 0;
    for(int i=2; i<n; ++i)
        if(!n%i)return 0;
    return 1;
}

int nextPrime(int n)
{
    for(int i=n+1; ; ++i)
        if(isPrime(i))return i;
}

int main(void){

    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("%d", nextPrime(n));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you test your isPrime function?

Comment: Your `isPrime()` function returns `1` for every number (except 0 and 1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here `!n%i` which is `(!n)%i` and it is always zero (for n != 0) as `!` has a bigger priority than `%`

You want:

```
if(!(n%i))return 0;
```

https://godbolt.org/z/Pcxc4746c